How would the Hebrews have light on Shabbat?
How did the Hebrews have light on Shabbat when it’s against Torah to light a fire.
Or say if it went out and it was pitch black, or very cold?

By lighting fire when it's not shabbat

Oil lamps can burn for many hours before going out, with a large enough reservoir, they can last all Shabbos.
